# Datatable column select filter sort() not working when column have link

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, datatables

I am using datatable column select filter. In one of the column I have html link tag, this cause to show unsorted select options at the top

```
<th><a href="{{route('customer.information', $customer->id)}}">{{ $customer->name }}</a></th>
```

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#colSearch').DataTable( {
         "order": [],

         initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]).every( function () {
               var column = this;
               var colTitle = this.header().innerHTML;
               var select = $('<select><option value="">Select ' + colTitle + '</option></select>')
                  .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                  .on( 'change', function () {
                     var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                     );

                     column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                  } );

               column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                  var val = $('<div/>').html(d).text();
                  select.append( '<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>' );
               } );
            } );
         }
      } );
   } );
   </script>
```

You can check the example datatable http://live.datatables.net/cikaqoxe/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because:

(1) `column.data()` extracts the entire contents of each column cell - including any HTML which may also exist in the cell.

(2) you are then sorting that extracted data. Therefore, instead of sorting using `Tiger Nixon`, you are actually using `<a href="">Tiger Nixon</a>`.

To fix this you can wait until you have removed the HTML before you sort your data. For example:

```js
var opts = [];
column.data().unique().each( function ( d, j ) {
  opts.push( $('<div/>').html(d).text() );          
} );
opts.sort();
opts.forEach(function (item, index) {
  select.append( '<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>' );
} );
```